# FreeRTOS queues as interrupts

Tags: c, freertos

Good day

I would like to find out if the queues in FreeRTOS work as software interrupts.

For example: I call `xQueuePeek()`/`xQueueReceive()` in `Thread1`, but the queue is empty. If I sometime later add an item to the queue in `Thread2`, does the FreeRTOS kernel recognize that there is something in the queue and immidiately jump to the previously unfulfilled `xQueuePeek()`/`xQueueReceive()`?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does, provided that

1. Task preemption is enabled (default setting)
2. Thread 1 is the highest priority thread in ready state (which is also true for most of the time (see bellow), otherwise Thread 2 wouldn't be running)

Things work differently when the pusher is an ISR instead of Thread 2. In this case, task switching doesn't take place unless `portYIELD_FROM_ISR(xHigherPrioritytaskWoken)` (or some equivalent function valid for the port) is explicity called with a `true` argument at the end of ISR. And remember that `xHigherPrioritytaskWoken` is set by `*FromISR()` functions. AFAIK, this pattern is the common practice.

Condition 2 I mentioned above may be **un**satisfied if some ISR 3 omits `portYIELD_FROM_ISR()` to awaken some highest priority Thread 3 (thus lowest priority Thread 2 runs even though higher priority Thread 3 is ready), and then ISR 1 pushes to the queue and calls `portYIELD_FROM_ISR()`. In this case, execution jumps to Thread 3 instead of Thread 1.

**Update:**

Okay, my above answer may sound confusing, so let me add a more generalized explanation:

When `xQueueSend()` is called, two things happen:

1. The tasks blocked on `xQueueReceive()` get their states updated to *"ready to run"*.
2. If preemption is enabled, kernel runs the scheduler. It looks for the highest priority task which is in *ready* state. According to the priorities of the tasks in ready state, a context switch may or may not take place.

When `xQueueSendFromISR()` is called from ISR, the flow is similar, but **"2"** happens only if `portYIELD_FROM_ISR()` is called with a `true` argument at the end of the ISR.